# Unreal engine 4 on browsers

Tags: game-engine, unreal-engine4

i'm new in game development and I recently working with phaser 3. But I saw great things unreal 4 can do, and I want to explore this. But right now, I need to develop for Browsers, phaser games are really light and the browser can deal with them very well. 
So my question is, can the browser deal with unreal engine 4? 
The games will be heavy? 
It's worth to use it? 
There is another engine that can do as much as unreal and it's better on browser?

Thanks so much you all! 
Best regards! 
Sorry if is a dumb question!

Answer (score 0):

I used and compared the unreal engine
Phaser.io
Poor code structure
There's little in terms of cohesiveness in classes, methods or patterns.
 
vs 
Unreal Engine 4

When comparing Phaser.io vs Unreal Engine 4, the Slant community recommends Phaser.io for most people. In the question“What are the best 2D game engines?” Phaser.io is ranked 8th while Unreal Engine 4 is ranked 18th. The most important reason people chose Phaser.io is:

If you're browsing Slant, you probably already have a JavaScript enabled browser, which is most of what you need to get started learning JavaScript. The requirement to run a server locally on your computer while developing might make things a little more difficult

Unreal engine

SPECS
Languages
JavaScript; TypeScript
Distributed targets
HTML5
License
MIT
Price
Free
Languages
C++, Blueprints (Visual Scripting)
API Support
DirectX 10, DirectX 11, Vulkan (SM5), OpenGL
Console targets
PlayStation 4